# Jasper reports data filtering

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working with jasper reports, supplying data through the `JRMapCollectionDataSource`. To be specific, each row is smth like this:

```
{"id"->"21552", "name"->"", "date"->"22.03.2013"}
```

Now I need to include to the report only those records, where `id` is greater than 10, for instance. What shall I do?

I've discovered `filterexpression` tag, but it only works with subdata sets. Then, how I can apply it to the main dataset?

When I'm trying to put `filterexpression` inside the `jasperReport` tag, iReports fails with error:
thanks a lot for your response, I've tried to do so. I report gives me

> exception:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter expressions are not limited to sub-datasets. Simply put the `filterExpression` tag inside the `jasperReport` tag and it will be applied to the main dataset.

Placement is important, it seems. The filter expression must come before any content, but after the fields are declared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I've tried to do so, but iReports gives an exception in such case, I updated my answer with the exception message.

Comment: Interesting. You used to be able to use filter exprssions in the main report, but it seems that this function has been removed in the more recent versions of jasperreports

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I get the same exception if I place the tag incorrectly. It must come before any content (pageHeader, detail, etc.) but AFTER any fields. I'm not sure if any other tags affect it. Try playing around with the placement to find something that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, GenericJon! It worked! I didn't try to place it after fields declaration. Seems to be logical, fields should be defined before search criteria, but not too straight forward =) Thanks a lot again.